# SVN Mac - commiting files with an "@" in their name

Tags: macos, svn

I am using the default SVN client on Mac that you use with the terminal. The problem is I want to commit three files that contains an "@" in them, and only those files. However it does not seem to work, SVN cannot read the @ for some reason. I did it like this:

```
svn commit Assets/Monkey@Prime.pck -m "test"
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the syntax for [peg revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html). This is the workaround suggested in the manual:

> The perceptive reader is probably wondering at this point whether the
>   peg revision syntax causes problems for working copy paths or URLs
>   that actually have at signs in them. After all, how does svn know
>   whether news@11 is the name of a directory in my tree or just a syntax
>   for “revision 11 of news”? Thankfully, while svn will always assume
>   the latter, there is a trivial workaround. **You need only append an at
>   sign to the end of the path, such as news@11@**. svn cares only about
>   the last at sign in the argument, and it is not considered illegal to
>   omit a literal peg revision specifier after that at sign. This
>   workaround even applies to paths that end in an at sign—you would use
>   filename@@ to talk about a file named filename@.

Ugly, isn't it? :)